# On union and intersection of non Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that union and intersection of two Lebesgue mble sets are also Lebesgue mble. My questions is about the same thing for non mble sets.
1. Does there exist two non mble sets(whose union is not the whole R) whose union is mble?
2. Does there exist two non mble sets(with nonempty intersection) whose intersection is mble?

Comment: I have answered your updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ be any non-measurable set and let $Y=\mathbb{R}\setminus X$ be its complement, which will necessarily also be non-measurable. Then $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $X\cap Y=\varnothing$ are measurable.

Now let $Z=Y\cup\{x\}$ and $W=X\setminus \{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. Then $W$ and $Z$ are necessarily non-measurable, and $X\cap Z=\{x\}$ and $W\cup Y=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ are both measurable.